# How to drop duplicates in dataframe ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df:

```
  print df

  Name | Company     |
  Mark |XYZ Corp     |
  Mark |    XYZ Corp |

  df = df.drop_duplicates()
  print df

  Name | Company     |
  Mark |XYZ Corp     |
  Mark |    XYZ Corp |
```

I want to ignore any leading or preceding whitespaces and drop duplicates.

Comment: You'd have to `lstrip` and `rstrip` first and then drop duplicates but do you want to modify the data or leave it with white spaces after dropping duplicates? also what would do for `'A B'` and `'A     B'` and `'A-B'` and `'A - B'`?

Comment: That was a Typo. I didn't mean to type 'A- B' and 'A - B'. I want to modify the data. I will try applying lstrip and rstrip, that should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vectorised [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and you can then call `drop_duplicates`:

```
In [271]:
df['Company'] = df['Company'].str.strip()
df.drop_duplicates()

Out[271]:
   Name   Company
0  Mark  XYZ Corp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strip` to remove the white space before dropping the duplicates e.g.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  df.loc[i, "Company"] = df.loc[i, "Company"].strip()
```